# Resuming a Paused NSTimer

Tags: ios

So after looking at possibly every NSTimer Pause/resume on this site nothing has worked for me when it comes to resuming the timer. Pausing and starting the timer work flawlessly with no problems. The Resume function on the other hand nothing.

My Timer is called by

```
[tickerTimer invalidate];
tickerDate = [NSDate date];
tickerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(runTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And the timer itself

```
-(void)runTimer {
    NSTimeInterval interval = [tickerDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
    seconds = ABS((int)interval);
    minutes = seconds/60;
    hours = minutes/60;
    hhmmssLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes%60, seconds%60];
}
```

The Pause Function is

```
pauseStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
previousFireDate = [tickerTimer fireDate];
NSDate *date = [NSDate distantFuture];
[tickerTimer setFireDate:date];
```

And finally that resume that wont work is

```
float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];    
[tickerTimer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
```

Am i using the fireDate incorrectly or is there a better way to pause and resume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you invalidate the current timer and create a new timer instance ?

Like:

```
-(void)pauseTimer
{
    [tickerTimer invalidate];
}

-(void)resumeTimer
{
    tickerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(runTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: Would that keep the time that it was paused at?

Comment: @inVINCEable: No, you can keep a `NSDate` object for that.

Comment: So if i added whats there to my current pause and resume would i keep the date and still start the timer?

Comment: @inVINCEable: what is the use of `pauseStart` and `previousFireDate` ?

Comment: to be honest im not really sure about the pauseStart, but im pretty sure the fire date is an NSDate save to save the timer position

Comment: @inVINCEable: ok, No need of that. Because you can't pause and resume a timer. Only way is to stop the current one and Start a new one. So no need to preserve the stopped time, unless you need for other manipulations like how much time the timer ran etc

Comment: The goal is to record the time while the player is doing an action when they stop id like the timer to stop but the resume again when they resume

Comment: @inVINCEable: I may be wrong, but didn't you post a question about displaying the "total running time" some time ago? The question was deleted after I wrote an answer :-) Please accept my apologies if that wasn't you!

Comment: @MartinR it was about pausing a timer

Answer (score 0):

You can't pause a timer. However, when the user goes to the settings view, you can save the fireDate of the timer and also the current date. After this you invalidate the timer and let the user do his/her stuff. Once he/she switches back to the game, you create a new timer object and set the fire date to the old fire date plus the time the user was in the menu (oldTime + currentTime).

You can use this code to implement pause and resume functionality in NSTimer

**//=========new timer update method=============**

```
-(void) updateTimer {

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];


NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss.S"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];

NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
lblMessage.text = timeString;
pauseTimeInterval = timeInterval;

}

 -(IBAction) startBtnPressed:(id)sender
    {
//=============================new update with start pause==================
if(running == NO) {
    running = YES;

    startDate = [NSDate date] ;
    startDate = [[startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((-1)*(pauseTimeInterval))] retain];
    stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
else {
    running = NO;
    [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
    stopWatchTimer = nil;
    [self updateTimer];
}
}
```

declare in .h file NSDate startDate;

```
    NSTimeInterval pauseTimeinterval; and in viewdidload pausetimeInterval=0.0;
```

Let me know if you face some problem.

Comment: I changed the date formatter to hh:mm:ss and it starts at exactly 7 hours